# Which one is better for removed content, 301 or 404?

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, joomla, http-status-code-404

We fed up with duplicate links of Joomla and we converted our website from Joomla to Html. Because in Joomla we have only (approx) 80 pages, but Google indexed 1970(!) pages. That means duplicate content for Google. So we converted it to Html. But what we can do for the old pages?

Our new link structure is domainname.com/article.html

But the old structure was domainname.com/index.php/article.php

So, which is better for the old pages, 301 redirect or 404 not found? What should we do?

Comment: Joomla would never give you a url like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the content has *moved* then it is `301 Moved Permanently` (coupled with a `Location` header to say where it has moved to).

If the content has been *removed* then it is `410 Gone`.

`404 Not Found` is for content that never existed or can't be found for unknown reasons.

---

It sounds like you want to `301` all the URLs where the duplicate content used to be available to the one place that it is now available.

Comment: Thank you Quentin for your answer. Our content is renewed, so they are fresh and unique. But the old pages are 2 years old. So we don't want the old ones. Also, link structure has changed as I mentioned above. So, is it 410 Gone is better for us? And how can we do this? For example, can we add some code to any page like " domainname.com/index.php/*? is 410"

Comment: You don’t need to keep the old *pages*, but you should keep their *URLs* if the resources still exist, in renewed form. Using 301 redirect for the those URLs is the way to ensure that the old URLs stored in search engines, links around, bookmark lists, etc. keep working. You want that everyone using an old URL gets the corresponding new content (and information about the current URL); this is what 301 is for.

Comment: Thanks Jukka, but we don't want to old urls stored in search engines. Because almost all of them got backlinked from spam sites, link farms. We want to fresh start for clean seo. So, is 301 hurt us or not? And how can we do that, with htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

`404 Not Found:` The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.

`301 Moved Permanently:` The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned URIs. Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically re-link references to the Request-URI to one or more of the new references returned by the server, where possible. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.

In my opinion, if the page you are removing has a suitable alternative page on your web site, then 301 it. Do not always 301 the page to your home page. If there is no suitable, and by suitable I mean, a page that is very similar to the page you are removing, then 404 the page.

301 if there is a related and similar page to the page you are removing. 404 if there is not.

You can see complete blog here: http://www.seroundtable.com/404-301-web-page-16773.html